# Height and width in dp looks different on different devices (Android)

Tags: android

According to this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zhszwkcay2A)

If I want create some element, which must looks the same on devices with different dpi (Phone, Tablet, TV).

As shown on video (at 4:52), I must specify dimensions of this element in dp.

But I got this (Redmi Note vs Redmi 1s (android 4.2.2 on both)):

[image]

(I use IntelliJ Idea 14)

Here is my code from activity:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:textSize="60sp"/>

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="#ff080808">

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:text="New Button"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Questions:**

Why line height is not match on phones?

Why button is smaller on smaller screen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between "px", "dp", "dip" and "sp" on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/what-is-the-difference-between-px-dp-dip-and-sp-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

- px is one pixel.
- sp is scale-independent pixels.
- dip is Density-independent pixels.

> You would use

sp for font sizes

dip for enter code hereeverything else.

dip==dp

[image]

**dp**

> Density-independent Pixels - an abstract unit that is based on the
>   physical density of the screen. These units are relative to a 160 dpi
>   screen, so one dp is one pixel on a 160 dpi screen. The ratio of
>   dp-to-pixel will change with the screen density, but not necessarily
>   in direct proportion. Note: The compiler accepts both "dip" and "dp",
>   though "dp" is more consistent with "sp".

[image]

[Refer this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-between-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android)